# Windows Batch file (taking multiple input as same time and using them separately)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to take several input from user and use those input separately as a argument to call another .ttl file.
for example : when i run my batch file 
I take user input like : 23,34,45,56,76,44
so how do i access each input like (23 or 34 or 45) separately ?
as i want to call _acb.ttl file wit argument 24 and 
_bfc.ttl file with 34 and so on...

I want to do it inside the batch file not as an Argument.

Comment: How are you taking your input from the user? As in, from the command line as argument(s) or as part of the script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get user input - batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247390/how-to-get-user-input-batch) and [I need a way to prompt a user for input using batch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14942553) and several others.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET /p userinput="please enter data separated by commas or spaces "
CALL :getarg 1
ECHO arg 1 is %argument%
CALL :getarg 3
ECHO arg 3 is %argument%
CALL :getarg 2
ECHO arg 2 is %argument%

GOTO :EOF

:getarg
CALL :nabarg %1 %userinput%
GOTO :eof

:nabarg
SETLOCAL
SET num=%1
:nabargl
SHIFT
IF %num% neq 1 SET /a num-=1&GOTO nabargl
endlocal&SET argument=%1
GOTO :eof
```

Simple!